# SQL Server 2012 : insert data into table while checking for duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, excel-2010

I have written a query to insert data into a SQL Server table from Excel, and I need to add to check and see if that information is already in the table. When I add a `WHERE` clause to check the table to see if the data I'm about to insert is actually new, it will not add any data, even if it is new.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Master 
(
    BrNBr varchar(10),
    BranchName varchar(100),
    Region varchar(100),
    Marketplace varchar(100),
    Enumber varchar(120),
    Fname varchar(100),
    Lname varchar(100),
    SBSLFName varchar(100),
    SBL varchar(100),
    Title varchar(100),
    Status varchar(100),
    StartDate int
);

INSERT INTO #Master (BrNbr, BranchName, Region, Marketplace, Enumber, Fname, Lname, SBSLFName, SBL, Title, Status, StartDate)
VALUES ('TT000', 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'T77777', 'Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6', 'Test7', 'SBS', 'A', '42005');

INSERT INTO dbo.tbSBSTest
  SELECT DISTINCT
     BrNbr,
     BranchName,
     Region,
     Marketplace,
     Enumber,
     Fname,
     Lname,
     SBSLFName,
     SBL,
     Title,
     Status,
     CONVERT(int, StartDate, 102) AS Startdate,
     NULL AS Termdate
  FROM 
     #Master
  WHERE 
     Enumber NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Enumber FROM dbo.tbSBSTest);

DROP TABLE #Master

SELECT *
FROM dbo.tbSBSTest
WHERE BranchName = 'Test1';
```

Pardon the formatting - it's being written by Excel. The unique identifier is the `Enumber`. If I comment out the `WHERE` clause it will update, but it will not with the `WHERE` clause in use.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx), with a condition, instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.BrNbr, M.BranchName, M.Region...
FROM #Master AS M
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT T.Enumber FROM Database.dbo.tbSBSTest AS T WHERE T.Enumber = M.Enumber)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks.  The follow up question:  WHY Would NOT EXISTS work when my previous method would not?  I use a similar WHERE Clause is many queries with no problems.  WHERE X NOT IN .....

Comment: The difference between NOT IN and NOT EXISTS is mainly how they treat nulls. I don't know why your initial query didn't work, as I don't have the data from tbSBSTest, but I thought it would be worth a try with exists ;-) You can read more about the different methods here: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

No need to check with a `WHERE`, the DB engine itself provides a mechanism for checking for duplicates, `UNIQUE` constraints, indexes and primary keys. You need to create such constraint on the target table, then it will automatically (and way more efficiently) reject duplicate records based on a set of columns. You can add the constraint to the existing table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbSBSTest] ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_tbSBSTest_Enumber UNIQUE(Enumber) ;
```

This will cause any `INSERT` that contains a duplicated *enumber* column with something existing to be rejected. This certainly prevents duplicates, but a side effect is that the whole batch is rejected instead of just the duplicated ones. Another option for that case, so you can use the very same code as before, is to use the little known **ignore_dup_key** index option:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbSBSTest] ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_tbSBSTest_Enumber UNIQUE(Enumber) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON) ;
```

This causes SQL Server to silently ignore those rows that have a enumber value that is already there, but otherwise happily accept all others. Here is an article with this idea in more detail http://web.archive.org/web/20180404165346/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/02/01/a-creative-use-of-ignore-dup-key.aspx.

Note that is also doesn't comes without its side effects, have a look here too [Why would you NOT set IGNORE_DUP_KEY to ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/533659/2557263)

Comment: I didn't know about this feature (IGNORE_DUP_KEY), so thanks for sharing this (+1). But after reading about the side effects, I would personally choose a simple where-clause anytime. It feels a bit like tricking the DB to ignore errors, rather than actually making sure there are none.

Comment: @Mackan Sure, it's a tradeoff. But at the very least I would use the plain constraint to ensure that no bad data ever makes into the DB, plus the `WHERE` to ensure the inserts succeed. The index will also make the lookups faster.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a left outer join. It will allow you to join on multiple columns if Enumber is not unique

```
CREATE TABLE #Master ( BrNBr VARCHAR (10) ,BranchName VARCHAR (100) ,
Region VARCHAR (100) ,Marketplace VARCHAR (100), 
Enumber VARCHAR (120) ,Fname VARCHAR (100) ,Lname VARCHAR (100) ,
SBSLFName VARCHAR (100) ,SBL VARCHAR (100) ,
Title VARCHAR (100) ,Status VARCHAR (100) ,StartDate INT)

INSERT INTO #Master  (BrNbr,BranchName,Region,Marketplace,Enumber,
Fname,Lname,SBSLFName,SBL,Title,Status,StartDate) 
VALUES('TT000','Test1','Test2','Test3','T77777',
'Test4','Test5','Test6','Test7','SBS','A','42005')

INSERT INTO Database.dbo.tbSBSTest
SELECT DISTINCT m.BrNbr,m.BranchName,m.Region,m.Marketplace,
m.Enumber,m.Fname,m.Lname,m.SBSLFName,m.SBL,m.Title,m.Status,
CONVERT(INT,m.StartDate,102) AS Startdate, NULL AS Termdate
FROM #Master m
LEFT OUTER JOIN Database.dbo.tbSBSTest t on t.Enumber = m.Enumber 
WHERE t.Enumber IS NULL

DROP TABLE #Master

SELECT * FROM Database.dbo.tbSBSTest
WHERE BranchName = 'Test1'
```