# SQL Server 2008 Insert fails reporting

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, sql-insert

I have unique constraints on both Username and Nickname fields.  When I run the following code with a duplicate Nickname then SQL Server 2008 reports Err 23000 Violation of Unique Key constraint.  But when I run it with a duplicate Username no Error is thrown (though the Message "Affected Rows: 0" results and no changes are effected to the table).

I don't understand why this should be or how to deal with this (I want an error thrown in either instance).  Thanks in advance.

INSERT INTO Members (UserName, Nickname)
VALUES ('bob', 'bob55')

---

```
CREATE TABLE [Members].[Members] (
[GUID] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) ,
[UserName] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL ,
[NickName] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL ,
)


-- ----------------------------
-- Indexes structure for table Members
-- ----------------------------
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [Index:UserName] ON [Members].[Members]
([UserName] ASC) 
WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
GO

-- ----------------------------
-- Primary Key structure for table Members
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE [Members].[Members] ADD PRIMARY KEY ([GUID])
GO

-- ----------------------------
-- Uniques structure for table Members
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE [Members].[Members] ADD UNIQUE ([NickName] ASC)
GO
ALTER TABLE [Members].[Members] ADD UNIQUE ([UserName] ASC)
GO
```

Comment: Please show your table def and the insert statements.

Comment: That behaviour is consistent `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`, which is in your DDL. But I don't know why its ignoring the other two constraints. Start by changing `ON`  to `OFF`. Is it that way for any reason?

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533659/why-would-you-not-set-ignore-dup-key-to-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to make field unique in SQL Server:

1. unique constraint
2. unique index

When you create an unique index, you can set a database behavior in case of trying to insert duplicate value:

- `WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)` - do nothing, just ignore new record with duplicate value
- `WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)` - throw an exception

When you create an unique constraint, SQL Server in implicit way creates an unique index `WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)`

In your question you create 3 unique indexes: one explicit on the column UserName, and two impicit on both NickName and UserName fields. When you try to insert a record with duplicate UserName, the inserting stops on unique index violation and SQL Server ignores the record. There is no work for an unique constraint. But when you try to insert a record with duplicate NickName, an unique constraint generates an error.

If you want to get errors for both fields in same manner, just drop the unique index:
`DROP INDEX [Index:UserName] ON [Members].[Members]`

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Fwiw I am using Navicat 11 and for some reason when I create an Index it adds the IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON by default.

Am I correct in inferring then that if I have a unique index on a field I do not also need a unique constraint?  (I will test now but always like reassurance ;)

Comment: Upon testing yes, a unique index makes a unique constraint on the same field irrelevant.  Thanks again.